# How can I add "+" over a certain value with jQuery UI Slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a price slider with jQuery UI slider.
What I want to do is add "+" when the handle reaches the max value.
I added if statement but it didn't work.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider({
        range: "min",
        value: 2,
        min: 1,
        max: 50,
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
            $( "#amount").val( ui.value + "K");
            if($( "#amount" ).val(ui.value)>50){
                $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value + "K+");
            }
         }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( $( "#slider-range-min" ).slider( "value" ) + "K");
});
```

If somebody knows how to do this, that would be great.
Thank you!

Comment: Try `if($( "#amount" ).val(ui.value)>=50)` instead of `if($( "#amount" ).val(ui.value)>50)`

Comment: Can you create a fiddle showing the issue?

Comment: Thank you imtheman but this did not work.

Comment: Sorry try `if(ui.value>=50)`

Comment: @user3011308 I'm glad it worked for you. I've added an answer. Please mark it as accepted if it is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `slide` property should be:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
           if(ui.value>=50)
               $( "#amount" ).val( ui.value + "K+");
           else
               $( "#amount").val( ui.value + "K");
        }
```

The problem was that `$( "#amount" ).val(ui.value)` is used to set the value of `#amount`, but the value was already being passed in through the `ui` param. Also, since the maximum value for the slider is 50, then you will never get above it, so you must use `>=` or even just `==` would work as well.